# ns3-lte build failure when running python code using SEM (ns-3 simulation execution manager)

Tags: python, ns-3

I'm trying to run a `python` code using SEM, this code runs only in `ns3-mmwave-2.0` module, however during the `ns3-mmwave` building, it shows an `ns3-lte` error.
What could be the reason?, knowing that i can't use other versions of `ns3` because the code im trying to run can only work on this `mmwave` module version 2.

```
 Building ns-3:  62%|████████████▎       | 1563/2535 [10:29<6:47:36, 25.16s/file]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ns3-mmwave-2.0/thz-sem.py", line 103, in <module>
    campaign = sem.CampaignManager.new(
  File "/home/dang/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sem/manager.py", line 116, in new
    runner = CampaignManager.create_runner(ns_path, script,
  File "/home/dang/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sem/manager.py", line 209, in create_runner
    return locals().get(runner_type,
  File "/home/dang/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sem/runner.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.configure_and_build(path, optimized=optimized)
  File "/home/dang/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sem/runner.py", line 148, in configure_and_build
    for current, total in pbar:
  File "/home/dang/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1176, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home/dang/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sem/runner.py", line 169, in get_build_output
    raise Exception("Compilation ended with an error"
Exception: Compilation ended with an error.
STDERR
b"In file included from ../../src/lte/model/epc-mme-application.cc:30:\n../../src/lte/model/epc-s11-sap.h: In member function \xe2\x80\x98void ns3::EpcMmeApplication::DoInitialUeMessage(uint64_t, uint16_t, uint64_t, uint16_t)\xe2\x80\x99:\n../../src/lte/model/epc-s11-sap.h:183:10: error: \xe2\x80\x98msg.ns3::EpcS11SapSgw::CreateSessionRequestMessage::<anonymous>\xe2\x80\x99 may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]\n  183 |   struct CreateSessionRequestMessage : public GtpcMessage\n      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\ncc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors\n\nBuild failed\n -> task in 'ns3-lte' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)\n"
STDOUT
b''
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixing requires the initialization of the structures and variables.

Update: Apparently there is a waf option to disable these kinds of warnings from being treated as errors: `--disable-werror`.